# Access 2007 VBA - Is There a Variable that Indicates if a Report Was Printed?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access 2007 and it contains a report that I usually run with this VBA code:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSales", acViewPreview
```

I click the "Close Print Preview" button on the ribbon if I don't need to print the report.

But once in a while I want to print the report, so I click the Print button on the ribbon,
which launches the Print Dialog box, and I click OK to print.

Here's my question - is there a way to know if a report was printed?  For example, is there
a variable I can refer to after the report closes (like acReportPrinted) that tells me if the report was printed and not just previewed?

I want to keep track of how many copies were printed.

Thank you.

Comment: Not that I know of. Preview is basically the same as print.

Comment: You could use a message box to ask to either print or preview, and disable the print functionality if they select preview (maybe display the report in a form is the easiest route), and save a record if they choose the print action.

Comment: Good ideas.  Thanks.